# Evaluate a sum involving n choose r

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation, factorial

Evaluate: $\sum_{k=0}^6 (-1)^k \binom{6}{k}$ where $\binom{n}{r}= \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

I'm unsure how to compute the part with $\binom{6}{k}$, it should be something along the lines of $\frac{6!}{k!(6-k)!}$ can we simplify this down?

I think there was an expansion method for factorials I could used in the denominator that was somewhere along the lines of $(6-k)(5-k)(4-k)(3-k)(2-k)(1-k)$ ?

Comment: A fun way to do this: look at [Pascal's triangle](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1114&bih=599&q=pascal%27s+triangle&oq=pascal%27s+triangle&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1558.6285.0.6403.31.16.7.8.8.0.118.1147.14j2.16.0...0.0...1ac.1.14.img.sIo4RYqoOrI).  The numbers you wish to sum are those in the $7$th row, with alternating signs, beginning with a positive sign.  You should get $0$.  Try the same computation, making sure to alternate signs, with any other row except the first.  What do you get?

Comment: Clearly all rows sum to zero that way, figured this had some connection to pascal and some kind of expansion.

Comment: It's not so clear to me, but it is in fact true.  Here is the [proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most transparent way to look at this is to use the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), as both earlier answers suggest,
$$
(p+q)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^{n-k}q^k
$$
and then set $n=6$, $p=1$, $q=-1$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for clearing it up!

Comment: You're welcome. This proof is a favorite of textbook authors. Try it with $p=1$, $q=2$ to get another mysterious-seeming identity.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$nCr:=\binom{n}r\,,\;\;\text{and by the Binomial Theorem (Newton), we get :}$$

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nka^{n-k}b^k$$

Substitute above now with $\,a= 1 \;,\;b = -1\;,\;n=6$ ...

Comment: I think you mean a=1

Comment: a^(n-k) = 0 for what you have given me in every case, however (0 + 1)^6 is 1. Bit confused here.

Comment: @Bob R, $k$ should run from $0$ to $n$. DonAntonio goofed slightly.

Comment: "slightly"? That's an understatement. Thanks, it's been edited and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The binomial theorem tells that that: $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array}\right)x^iy^{n-i}$$where $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array}\right)$ is your nCi. Maybe some clever choices for $x$, $y$, and $n$ will make your summation easier.

Comment: so then from what I'm given y = 0; x = -1 i = k = 0; n = 6 y^n−i will always be 0 and the sum will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has been answered a few times, let's answer a more general question of the same form.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^m(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}
&=\sum_{j=k}^m(-1)^j\left(\binom{n-1}{j}+\binom{n-1}{j-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=k}^m(-1)^j\binom{n-1}{j}+\sum_{j=k-1}^{m-1}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j}\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}{m}+(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}
\end{align}
$$
The third equality takes advantage of the term by term cancellation for $j=k$ throught $j=m-1$. This leaves only the $j=m$ term on the left and the $j=k-1$ term on the right.

In the particular case at hand, $k=0$ and $m=n=6$. Since $\displaystyle\binom{5}{6}=\binom{5}{-1}=0$, the sum is $0$.